# Converse of compactness

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

> If $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, the image of a compact set under $f$ is compact.

Is the converse true? I suspect is false, but I have no idea of how to construct the counterexample.

Comment: If by converse you mean "The image of compact sets of $f$ is compact, then $f$ is continuous", then take a function which only takes two values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the range of $f$ is finite and it has more than one point, then $f$ is discontinuous (since the range is not connected) but $f$ maps compact sets onto compact sets.